# Subprocess not working ~ Opening Game Script w/ a Menu Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

When I'm using subprocess to open my game script using my menu script, I get an odd error that I can't seem to fix even if I try reinstalling python or pygame. Am I using the code incorrectly or something ?

~ INFORMATION~
Python Version 2.7.6
Pygame Verison 1.9.1

~ Error Given ~

```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Maze\menu.py", line 22, in <module>
>     subprocess = Popen(['swfdump', 'main.py', '-d'], stdout=PIPE)   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
>     errread, errwrite)   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
>     startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

~ Code I'm Using For My Menu ~

```
    import pygame
import dumbmenu as dm
pygame.init()
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Just a few static variables
red   = 255,  0,  0
green =   0,255,  0
blue  =   0,  0,255

size = width, height = 340,240  
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(blue)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.key.set_repeat(500,30)

choose = dm.dumbmenu(screen, [
                        'Start Game',
                        'Quit Game'], 64,64,None,32,1.4,green,red)

if choose == 0:
    pprocess = Popen(['swfdump', 'main.py', '-d'], stdout=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
elif choose == 1:    
    pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument to `Popen()` is `['swfdump', 'main.py', '-d']`, which would execute
something named `swfdump` with the arguments `main.py -d`. I suspect, you want something different. From [the fine documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pprocess = Popen('swfdump main.py -d', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
```

See if that works. If you really want to use a list you could do `['swfdump main.py -d',]` and `shell=False` instead i think.